# Printing data types - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String
                     , lastName :: String
                     , age :: Int
                     } deriving (Show)


buffy = Person "Buffy" "Summers" 22
burt = Person "Burt" "Reynolds" 23
cloud = Person "Cloud" "Strife" 22
rick = Person "Rick" "Sanchez" 21

people = [buffy,burt,cloud,rick]
```

I'm looking for multiple ways of printing the `firstName`s of each element within the `people` list.

Printing these elements can be printed in forms such as:

- `x1,x2,x3,...xn`
- `[x1,x2,x3,...xn]`
- Multiple lines:

  ```
  x1  
  x2   
  x3   
  ...  
  xn
  ```

Comment: You say you are looking for "multiple ways" - how should these different methods differ? Should they print each element differently? One way is `mapM_ print people`, another is `sequence_ (map print people)`, does this count as two different ways?

Comment: Yes, I'm just interested in seeing different methods of printing data types within Haskell.

Answer (score 4):

If you create a record type like `Person`, you get the following field selectors:

```
firstName :: Person -> String
lastName :: Person -> String
age :: Person -> Int
```

So you can `map firstName` over your list to turn your `[Person]` into a `[String]`.

Printing the `firstName`s, then, is a mere `mapM_ (putStrLn . firstName) people`.

Comment: Would this mean I would have to get rid of my attributes within my data structure and just have it read data Person = Person String String Int?

Comment: No, I mean if you define `Person` exactly as you do in your question, one of the things you get from that ("for free") is the selector function `firstName`. You don't need to (in fact, you can't, because of the naming clash) define `firstName`, the function, yourself if you already have `firstName`, the field.